# What happened to the styling?

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

It seems some styling is broken. I try to open the review page on some sites but their layout is really broken.

What is wrong?

[image: Sample 1]

[image: Sample 2]

<strike>It might be related to viewing from mobile, but I can't verify that now.</strike>

Verified now. It just happens when you view a desktop page using the mobile view.

Comment: Hmm, that's no good - taking a look

Comment: Ah I see the issue - a fix will rollout shortly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should now be fixed, apologies for that. Unifying some code didn't work correctly when there's the case of *this page doesn't have a mobile*.